# How can I override iFrame useragent to iPhone?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, iframe, user-agent

How can I force the iFrame in my website to behave like an iPhone browser and load the mobile website always?

Which means when someone visits the site from a desktop/mobile browser and wants that iFrame to load [www.nytimes.com], that iFrame will load the mobile site [m.nytimes.com].

Comment: what is this for? an iOS app? an Android app? a web app?

Comment: webapp. actually website has a iFrame in it. I want it to act like a iPhone browser which means I want it to load mobile site (m.nytimes.com) while I give it a desktop site url (www.nytimes.com).

Comment: so, if someone opens the website on their desktop computer, you still want the page to display the mobile version, as if it were an iPhone?

Comment: Exactly. bt how can I do that?